# Spring batch read input file with date and hours in it

Tags: xml, spring-batch

IN SPRING BACTH XML
I was trying to read the input file in flatfilereader whose name is something like this
`FILENAME_YYYYMMDD_YYYYMMD1HHMMSS.csv`
here YYYYMMDD is argument passed to job as businessdate, and YYYYMMD1 is D+1 ie. Next working day

I implemented the reader where I can able to read FILENAME_YYYYMMDD.csv as YYYYMMDD is coming from job argument.

```
<property name="resource" value="file:filelocation/filename_#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(jobParameters[businessdate])}.csv" />
```

But Not able to take D+1 as well as HHMMSS as input file has HHMMSS(their timestamp)
irrespective of job run how can I tackle this?

Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: it seems that you are already parsing `businessdate` from YYYYMMDD and passing it as a job parameter. Where are you doing that?

Comment: Im passing businessdate=YYYYMMDD as a job parameter, as I need to read it as businessdate in filename.

Comment: Where are you passing that parameter? Is it on the command line or in main method using java code? How is `businessdate` resolved? I'm asking because I believe you should not be coding in a SpEL expression. I would calculate `businessdate` + 1 upfront as `nextBusinessDate` and pass that as a job parameter as well. This avoids doing the math inside a SpEL expression.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I was passing businessDate as job parameter in command line. I got your point to take  business date. :D Although quite confused on input reading part, HHMMSS part? Let's suppose, file generates at HHMMSS i.e. 120000 , my job reader will read at timestamp HHMMSS 010000 then how will I read the input file whcihc is generated before?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Quite confused on HHMMSS part .  I try to implement this.


`<property name="resource" value="file:filelocation/filename_#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(jobParameters[businessdate])} _#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('HHmmss').format(new java.util.Date())}.csv`

But this is taking current HHMMSS , not the one which is present in input file. Is there any other we can implement this scenario?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine To avoid all of this issues , I can read the file name like this 
`Filename_businessDate_*.csv` or `Filename_businessDate_%s.csv`
This will solve all the issue of next business date and HHMMSS since there will be unique file for each businessDate. 
Any idea is it possible? I tried but it didn't worked. It was looking for * in the file name, but like %s or * in filename. It was not searching the pattern :/ Any lead on this one?